# sqlalchemy join as new_name filter new_name.column == value

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm looking for a way to reference joined table inside filter. My query is:

```
session.query(A).outerjoin(B, C, D).filter(B.column_b == 1, C.column_c == 2)
```

How can I do this kind of filtering without naming model B and C?

```
session.query(A).outerjoin(B, C, D).filter_by(column_b=1, column_c=2)
```

Doesn't work because filter_by tries to find 'column_b' and 'column_c' in D. aliased() and alias() also don't work.
I receive dict of field_to_value in a form `{"column_a": 0, "column_b": 1, "column_c": 2}` And I need to create a query out of it. Of course I could have a mapping like `{"column_a": A.column_b, "column_b": B.column_b, "column_c": C.column_c}`. But there should be a better way.

Is there any good way to do such filtering?

Answer (score 0):

filter_by applies on the last join so you should be able to break your outerjoins. Try:

```
session.query(A).outerjoin(B).filter_by(column_b == 1)
                .outerjoin(C).filter_by(column_c == 2)
                .outerjoin(D)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer. But this approach still implies that I know name of model column belongs to. I updated the question to be more specific with what I want to achieve.